# MVC HtmlHelper outside View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a class and call it from a razor viewpage in asp.net mvc3.
How can i pass the HtmlHelper from the View to my class ? 
I can do this but then ive got not all methods for example "RenderAction" and "RenderPartial"
are missing.

**Update**

I want to call a Partial View because its easier to implement (by the end user) and doesnt require a complete compilation of my site.

please note that the following example is NOT excactly what i want to do ;) I think my example is stupid, but it shows in generall what i want to do.

ViewPage: 
`HtmlString str = new Renderer().Render(this.Html)`

Code (behind):

```
  public class Renderer
    {
        HtmlHelper _html;

        public Renderer(HtmlHelper html)
        {
            this._html = html;
        }

        public HtmlString Render()
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            // getting html from a partial view
            return new HtmlString(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you have `using System.Web.Mvc.Html` ?

Comment: nice, using System.Web.Mvc.Html makes the method present. But is there a way to call "RenderAction" and get back the HtmlString ?

Comment: i cant post my snippet here, please see next "answer". thank you!

Comment: Damn i hate these days of 16 hours of coding ;) My Question was silly ;)
using System.Web.Mvc.Html makes the Methods visible
Everything else was unnessesary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was missing usings.

```
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
```

makes the Methods visible Everything else was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

`RenderAction()` and `RenderPartial()` are extension methods of [HtmlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx) you need to include the [System.Web.MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492706.aspx) namespace.

**Update**

You could use `@Html.RenderPartial("view")`

Or you could create an extension method of `HtmlHelper`

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions {

  public static IHtmlString MyRenderer(this HtmlHelper helper) {

    string html = String.Empty;
    //generate HTML here

    return new MvcHtmlString(html);

  }

}
```

Comment: nice, using System.Web.Mvc.Html makes the method present. But is there a way to call "RenderAction" and get back the HtmlString ?

Comment: You can invoke render action form the HtmlHelper. Can you provide some code of what you are trying to do and we may be able to better help?

Comment: i could not provide my "example" here as a comment, please see the next "answer"

Answer (score -1):

You really do not want to do presentation logic in your classes unless your class is dedicated for presentation functionality.  In that case you may want to simply make it an extension method off of HtmlHelper.

See these resources:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=406

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs